# How to create a grid view with two columns per row using RadListView

Tags: angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I thought this is easy, but unfortunately, I can not find out any answer.
I installed telerik-ui, and want to use RadListView. From the doc, I can see the demo page with perfect layout, to have mulitple items per row. In my case, I want to have two columns per row and then show the list view. Below is my xml code, but it is totally blank, I do not know why. Can you help?

This is the code in my XML:

```
<RadListView [items]="flattenDishes">
    <ListViewLinearLayout scrollDirection="Vertical" itemHeight="500" spanCount="2"></ListViewLinearLayout>
    <ng-template tkListItemTemplate let-flattenDish="item">
        <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="auto, *">
            <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
              <Image [src]="serverUrl +'images/' +  flattenDish.get('option_imageUrl') " stretch="aspectFill" width=200 height=200></Image>
              <Label  [text]="flattenDish.get('option_size')+':'+ flattenDish.getTrans('zh').get('title')"></Label>
              <Label  [text]="flattenDish.get('option_price')"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </GridLayout>
    </ng-template>
</RadListView>
```

Can anyone help me to have a working template here?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get this right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, is not with RadListView but the important part is inside the item:

```
 <ListView class="list-group" [items]="workOrders" (itemTap)="onItemTapSecondList($event)" separatorColor="gray">
            <ng-template let-workOrder="item">
                <StackLayout orientation="horizontal">
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label text="Order ref:" class="order-id-label"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label text="Order date:" class="order-id-label"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLAyout>
            </ng-template>
        </ListView>
```